# Cakephp 2.3: Efficient way to access model properties globally

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I want to be able to get the names of all models for whom a certain property is a certain value.

Ideally, I'd like to put a property in AppModel that is then inherited and subsequently set by all other models in such a way that it can be easily accessed from anywhere. This is the gist of my idea:

*Set this to **true** in any models I want to group:*

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $hasPortal = false;
}
```

*Then add this function to AppController:*

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar'); 
    static function getPortals() {
        $portalModels = array();    
        $models = App::objects('Model');
        foreach( $models as $model ) {
            if ( !class_exists($model) ) {
                $m = ClassRegistry::init($model);
                if ( $m->hasPortal ) {
                    $portalModels[] = $model;
                }
            }           
        }       
        return $portalModels;           
    }
}
```

Thus I can do this: `$portals = AppController::getPortals()` anywhere at all—and it works well enough for now (when I have >20 classes!), but I'm pretty sure it's foolishly inefficient. I want to be able to group collections of models (ideally even controllers and functions) on the fly for generating menus. But I'm quite green with OOP and have a lurking suspicion that this isn't the most efficient way to get the functionality I want.

**See the comments before reading on, I'm addressing a request to describe my specific context**

I'm not at *all* confident that this approach makes sense!

The actual thing I'm trying to implement is an automatically created menu in `home.ctp`. Using the above code, my `home.ctp` has this:

```
$portaledModels = AppController::getPortals();
foreach ($portaledModels as $model) {
    echo $this->element('modelPortal', array('model' => $model) );
}
```

*(Though eventually $model would be an array that holds descriptions, an icon link, etc.)*

It's often the case that, on the default 'home' page of a cake app, all I really want there is a means to navigate to various actions of many models—but not all (ie. `entries/index` and `authors/index` are obvious choices, whereas `entries_authors` has no value to users).

So in this case, I want to create an element that returns a nav interface for those models that should be accessible (this is NOT in lieu of ACL lists, I don't mean to use this for security, just the convenience of automating the content of home.ctp).

I know it's easy to manually create a list of such models and just update it when necessary. In general, though, I try to write nothing by hand that is available programmatically. It occurred to me that I could create a `models` model, basically a registry of what's in my app, and then `requestAction()` my way to the same effect. But then I got lost thinking about how to automatically have each model register itself when it's called, but only the first time? This is probably a good time to reaffirm to everyone that I am an **amateur** developer, hahaha. :)

Comment: To fix the error you can just make your `getPortals` function static - since that's how you're calling it. This doesn't look like a normal way to build a menu though - you're coupling your models, controllers and views all together by the look of it.

Comment: I agree with @AD7six on this, also, you'll be instantiating *every model* in your Application, which will not be very efficient. You may achieve similar results by defining an [Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) and check if a Model implements that interface via [`class_implements()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php)

Comment: AD7six Thanks, that solves one problem nicely!

@thaJeztah Thanks, I'll try that. I was very confident that this wasn't a good way to implement this kind of functionality, but not sure how it was best done. This is by no means enterprise-level software I'm writing, but learning best practices now seems wise for later!

Comment: What’s the problem you’re having, as it appears you may be trying to solve a problem by perhaps not the best means?

Comment: Best practices is to try to follow the conventions. @MartinBean is right to ask 'what are you trying to achieve', because scanning all models is not really 'standard'. You *may* of course have a valid reason to do this, but there may be other ways to solve it

Comment: I'm adding an account of what I want to actually do in my original post!! :) Thanks for taking this interest, guys!